# Can Cloud Run respond in less than 200ms?

Tags: google-cloud-run

Cloud Run seems to respond in over 400ms. even on repeated calls (I assume 'warmed up' containers).

I deployed a simple node.js service (see code below) that responds with a static JSON.

The service endpoint does not require user authentication. I am calling us-central1 (from Ventura County, CA. USA)

I call the service and get latency of above 400ms. Sometimes I see latency in the 5000-6000 ms. range!

I understand Cloud Run is in beta, but I'd appreciate feedback from Google on what I should expect for performance and approx. when. Also, if I am configuring something wrong, let me know. If you have better results than me - please let me know what you are doing differently.

Service I deployed: https://github.com/dorongrinstein/cloudrun-dummy-service

Test code: https://github.com/dorongrinstein/cloudrun-test

I expect the output to be in the double digit ms. range.
I get an output that is in the mid 3-digit range.

FYI - I am in Ventura County, CA. My internet connection is fine. I used gcpping.com and my median latency to us-central1 is 70ms.

Comment: Are you accounting for the reality of the cost of cold starts in serverless environments such as Cloud Run?  Accessing a function for the first time in a new server instance incurs the cost of instantiating that server instance prior to invocation.

Comment: How do you calculate the latency? What do you see in cloud run logs? Are you interacting with other component?

Comment: As you can see from the code example I've provided, I do not interact with any other components. I calculate latency as is shown in my second example (see github cloudrun-test repo).

Comment: See below. I submit 50 requests, then pause for 5 seconds (the container should still be up) and they submit another 50. The requests are still taking ~500ms. or more. This does not appear to be a cold/warm start issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Cloud Run can respond in less than 200ms.

You seemed to be hitting a [bug in our networking infrastructure](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139724101), which should now be fixed.

Comment: Yes, all is good now. I am very happy with Cloud Run so far. Keep up the good work. And thank you for being responsive and accommodating.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Cloud Run engineer](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19617205), you should expect similar cold start times in Cloud Run as in Cloud Functions.

One thing you could try is raising your containers' [memory limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits). At least in Cloud Functions startup latency [has been found](https://www.usenix.org/conference/atc18/presentation/wang-liang) to depend highly on memory allocation.

Comment: In cloud run, increasing memory don't increase CPU velocity, cloud function do.

Comment: If I submit 50 requests then pause for 5 seconds, and submit 50 subsequent requests, I still get ~500ms. (or sometimes 8000 ms. behavior). So, it is not a cold start. It is a running (should be) container that is responding in an unacceptably slow manner.

Comment: Alright. If you want to make absolutely sure it's not a case of cold starts you can [check your logs](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#how-can-i-tell-if-a-request-was-a-cold-start). How's your [concurrency limit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency), the default 80?

Comment: Container image URL
gcr.io/dorongrinstein-bw/dummy@sha256:50a8dd4cde481b5fa654f1b70249aaff0cacb2cae81f366508a2e0fa581ba580
Memory allocated
256MiB (default)
Concurrency
(system managed)
Request timeout
5 minutes (default)
Service account
Default Compute service account
Environment variables
None

Cloud SQL connections
None

Comment: Debugging a similar issue here https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/16nzuad/nextjs_start_time_is_extremely_slow_on_google/?sort=new